# Adding zero in front of a character in Python

Tags: python, regex, list

My input csv file looks as follows

S.No   first second third

1    71.28  75.30  79.78

2     3.45  36.65  25.4

My goal is to extract first two digits from first, second and third columns in each row.

I used list to store the output, which looks as follows.

```
['71','75','79']

['3.','36','25']
```

But I want have the following output ( in place of '3.' I want '03')

```
['71','75','79']

['03','36','25']
```

I tried my but best but unable to succeed. I am not sure where I was making mistake.

My try: For example, let  `a=['1','2','34']`

then I used print `str(a[0].zfill(2))` which outputs 01 which is what I needed,
but in case of main file this is not working.
Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to go through your list of strings, then convert each of them to a `float` (since it looks like you have some decimal points) and then convert them to a zero-padded number.

```
data = ['3.','36','25'];
new_data = ['%02d' % float(x) for x in data]
```

The [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) '%02d', indicates that you want an integer ("d") that if it has fewer than 2 digits will be zero padded ("02").

If you prefer the `format` method.

```
new_data = ['{0:02.0f}'.format(float(x)) for x in data]
```

This format specifier means that you want a zero-padded two digit number ("02") followed by zero points after the decimal (".0") and the input data type is a `float` ("f")

> **NOTE**: Both of these solutions assume that you don't care about any non-integer portions of the data (if there are any).

Answer (score 2):

Look up string formatting using '%'.  For example, you can use '%02d' to get leading zeros with an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Well am not a python programmer but if one has to use **`Regex`** to solve it then following one will find the desired number. which is single digit before decimal.

**Regex:** `\b(\d)\.\d*\b`

**Explanation:**

- `\b` at start and end maintains the word boundary.
- `(\d)\.\d*` matches the single digit with decimal part but **captures** only single digit.

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `0\1`. Where `\1` is captured single digit.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qT5nX4/2)**</kbd>

**Note:** Am not a python programmer. If anyone wishes to add demo of python program to this answer go ahead.